# AppScript Groups getUser() Permission Error

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, permissions, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm trying to use Google Apps Script to access the user list for a Group in my domain that I'm a member of, but I'm getting the error:

> Exception: You do not have permission to view the member list for the
> group

The reference documentation says "Throws an exception if you do not have permission to view the group's member list" but I *do* have permission to view the member list.

[Screenshot of group's "About" page showing I have permission to view the member list](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbnqT.png)

My code is just:

```
GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("group@domain.com").getUsers();
```

But obviously with the real group's email address. It works perfectly for groups that I am the owner or manager of, but not that I am a member of (again, even though I do have permission to see the member list). Is there another setting somewhere where I don't have that permission? Is the documentation just misleading and it never works for mere members?

Comment: are the project's files belong to the user that have permissions?

Comment: In addition to @SaarDavidson question, does the user who's running the script has the permissions to view the member list?

Comment: @JoseVasquez Yes, the project files belong to me, I am running them, and I have permission to view the member list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see in the **privacy** setting, **Group Members** can *view members*. In addition to that you have to make sure that the **Group Settings > Member Privacy > Who can view member email addresses** is set to (for instance) **Group Members** if you wanted other members and not only the owners and managers the access to list the users in that group.

Keep in mind that when using `GroupsApp.getGroupByEmail("group@domain.com").getUsers();` you get a list of **Users** where each user is a model that contains the email of each member, that's why you need access to the email addresses.